# GeneXus 18 cambiar servlet y static directory y/o cambiar web root

Tags: genexus, genexus18

estoy trabajando con GX 18 Upgr 7, generando Java-Web, Tomcat 9.
Al indicar el path del Tomcat, tal cual indica la documentacion de GX, se setea automaticamente el Servlet Directory & Static Content Directory, los cuales no pueden cambiarse/editarse.
Tambien se setea la Web Root, la cual si puede cambiarse.
Al cambiar la Web Root, sería de esperar que al hacer un "Rebuild All" se generara en la carpeta de Tomcat la respectiva para la aplicacion segun el nuevo nombre, pero esto no sucede.
Concretamente, necesitaría poder:

- Cambiar la Web Root y que dicha carpeta se genere, asi como las sub carpetas, clases, etc.
- En su defecto, si es "obligatorio" que la carpeta de Web Root coincida en nombre con las de Servlet & Static Content, necesitaria poder cambiar/editar estas carpetas.
  Gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 0):

En el ambiente "dev" de GeneXus el nombre de la webapp coincide con el de la KB+Environment. Servlet y Static no se pueden cambiar.

La alternativa que tenes es agregar un "alias" a tu webapp para que responda en otro nombre de webapp.

Ejemplo:

- Webapp real = "MiProyectoGx" =
  http://localhost:8080/MiProyectoGx/hlogin
- Webapp alias =
  "UnAliasAlProyecto" = http://localhost:8080/UnAliasAlProyecto/hlogin

Para lograr eso tenes que editar el archivo "servlet.xml" del Tomcat y agregar la siguiente linea adentro del elemento "Host":

```
<Context path="/UnAliasAlProyecto" docBase="/MiProyectoGx" />
```

Yo lo uso asi y me anda bien, pero una vuelta lei que las "/" pueden no ser necesarias en algun tipo de instalacion. Asi que si no te anda juga con eso.

Claramente un reinicio del tomcat es necesario para que tenga efecto.

Comment: Estimado Federico, primero que nada, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Estimado Federico, primero que nada, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. 
Te cuento que hice la modificación sugerida en el archivo "server.xml", y en principio me funcionó (tanto con/sin barra).
Por lo pronto, para el acceso/consumo a unos WS que tengo implementados, el "alias" sirve y es utilizado.
Después lo que por lo pronto no me funciono, fue el menu dinámico (que esta implementado con WWP / GAM Authorization), al hacer "click" en algún elemento, me lleva a la "real" , y ya no vuelvo al "alias". 
Seguiré probando, y si encuentro algo util, comentaré aquí.
Nuevamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Capaz ese link esta como "absoluto" y no "relativo". Fijate si podes hacer una prueba de poner un link que no incluya el nombre del DocBase. De esa forma el navegador deberia de entender que queres ir a esa URL a partir del DocBase en el que estas parado.